# How could I get all the informations of an OntClass?

Tags: jena, ontology

I am working on ontologies issues. I code in java and I'm using Jena in order to manipulate some RDF/Turtle files.
Now I would like collect all the informations of an OntClass just knowing his name.
For example, I have this OntClass:

```
@prefix isys: <http://myonto.installsys/rule#> .



isys:Rule
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:comment "design principle rules are used in SIDP documents"^^xsd:string ;
  rdfs:label "rule"^^xsd:string ;
  rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
      rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty ata:ata_number ;
      owl:someValuesFrom xsd:integer ;
    ] ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
      rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty isys:Number ;
      owl:someValuesFrom xsd:integer ;
    ] ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
      rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty isys:Object_1_a ;
      owl:someValuesFrom xsd:string ;
    ] ;
.
```

And I suppose that I just have the prefix and Rule so I can do

```
    OntClass Rule = onto.getOntClass("http://myonto.installsys/rule#Rule");
```

I am aware that I can use functions like `listEquivalentClass`or `listSublClasse`.

But I would like to know if there is a way to know all those informations with "one" function or I have to do it explicitly ?

Thank you, if you need more explications I will be glad to discuss

Comment: You can just list its properties with listProperties... maybe that's what you're after?

Comment: Yes I think I will use this one and do some treatments after.
Thank you for your help.